# SyntaxError: invalid syntax python main.py Помогите

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
python main.py
  File "main.py", line 48
   except Exception, e:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Помогите ошибка

```
import os
import sys
import re
import requests
from uuid import uuid4;

from telegram import InlineQueryResultAudio, ParseMode, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
import logging

import settings
import text
from constants import DATMUSIC_API_ENDPOINT
from constants import INLINE_QUERY_CACHE_TIME

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def inlinequery(bot, update):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    results = list()

    # search and trim result to 50, which is max result count for inline query answer
    audios = search(query)[:50]; 
    try:
        if audios:
            for audio in audios:
                results.append(
                    InlineQueryResultAudio(
                        id=uuid4(),
                        audio_url=audio['download'],
                        title=audio["title"],
                        performer=audio["artist"],
                        audio_duration=audio["duration"]
                    )
                )
            update.inline_query.answer(results=results, cache_time=INLINE_QUERY_CACHE_TIME)
    except Exception, e:
        error(bot, update, e)

def search(query):
    if len(query.strip()) < 1:
        query = text.get_random_artist()

    logger.info("Search query is '%s'" % query)

    payload = {'q': query};
    result = requests.get(DATMUSIC_API_ENDPOINT, params = payload);

    response = result.json()["data"];

    return response;

def error(bot, update, error):
    logger.warn('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))

def add_update_handlers(dp):
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", text.start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("about", text.about))

    dp.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(inlinequery))
    return dp

def main():
    token = os.getenv("DATMUSIC_BOT_TOKEN")
    if not token:
        logging.critical('NO TOKEN FOUND!')
        sys.exit()

    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater(token)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    add_update_handlers(dp)

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Block until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ну, строчка `try: Exception, e:` это действительно не верно. Возможно, вы имели в виду `except Exception as e:`

Comment: не помогло ! Что можно еще ?

Comment: Что значит «не помогло»?

Comment: у Вас две конструкции try на одном уровне, обе должны быть завершены по правилам (хотя там и просится except вместо второго try). Почитайте внимательно про синтаксис конструкции try .. except .. finally. И покажите кусок кода, где "не помогло"

Comment: Я попробовал переписать код

Comment: Какой версией Python запускаете?

Comment: Последней самой

Answer (score 1):

Такой синтаксис обработки исключений:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception, e:
    ...
```

это синтаксис Python 2. Т.к. у вас версия Python 3, то у вас должно быть

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

Comment: IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Comment: python main.py
  File "main.py", line 48
    try:

Comment: @ВалентинАлександрович, эта ошибка говорит о том, что у вас неправильно расставлены отступы в коде. `try` должен быть на том же уровне отступа, что и идущий выше него код.

Comment: File "main.py", line 48
    try:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ВалентинАлександрович, я взял ваш код из вопроса, поменял `except Exception, e:` на `except Exception as e:` - код запускается, ошибок синтаксиса нет.